# Spring Data Elasticsearch - ReactiveElasticsearchClient cannot save diacritics

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch `6.4.0` and spring-data-elasticsearch `3.2.4.RELEASE`. I create a ReactiveElasticsearchClient as:

```
    @Bean
    fun reactiveElasticsearchClient(): ReactiveElasticsearchClient {
        val clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(elasticsearchUrl)
            .build()
        return ReactiveRestClients.create(clientConfiguration)
    }
```

However when I save to the elasticsearch such source:

```
reactiveElasticsearchClient.index(new IndexRequest("test","test","1").source("{\"phrase\":\"diacritics test: ąćęłńóśźż\"}", XContentType.JSON)).block(Duration.ofSeconds(25))
```

It's saved in the cluster as:

```
     {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "test",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "phrase" : "diacritics test: ÄÄÄÅÅÃ³ÅÅºÅ¼"
        }
      }
```

How to set encoding for the reactive es client or fix it ?

Comment: How do you know that is is saved this way? I tried the same diacritics and saved an entity using the `ReactiveElaticsearchTemplate.save()` method (which under the hood creates a JSON and builds the `IndexRequest` with the same parameters). Doing a http request against Elasticsearch shows me it's indexed correcty, and retrieving the data with Spring Data Elasticsearch works as well.

Comment: I do a http request to "myelasticsearch:9200/test/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*" and this is what I get in response

Comment: same query here in my setup (same versions) works. Are you sure, that you java source code is in utf-8? Because that's a difference  see, I pass in the string from a client and send it on to ES whereas you have coded the characters in your source code.